# Is there any way to make Windows Media Player 12 convert more than one file at a time during sync?

Tags: audio, sync, windows-media-player

On a multi-core system, multiple concurrent conversions should speed up the sync process. I've looked for an option, but no dice. Is there a registry setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I know of or ever seen. I don't think Windows Media Player is multi core aware (Possibly excluding a few codecs).

If I was you, I would [submit it as a feature request](http://connect.microsoft.com/).